# ImageButton to open a new activity

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I am building an android app and on the main layout i have 3 Image Buttons which when clicked they must each open a new activity.

When I run the app and pressed on them the app crushes. this is the code i am using:

**MainActivity.java**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton converterbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);
    ImageButton placesbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagBtnPlace);
    ImageButton weatherbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtnweather);

     //Open Weather Activity
    if (weatherbtn.isPressed() == true) {
        weatherbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), weather_mainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }); //Open Currency Activity
    }else if (converterbtn.isPressed() == true) {
        converterbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CurrencyConverter_MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });//Open Places Activity
    } else if (placesbtn.isPressed()) {
        placesbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Places_mainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <activity android:name=".CurrencyConverter_MainActivity"/>
 <activity android:name=".weather_mainActivity"/>
```

Any ideas why that happens? **All the other posts ive checked** are doing it with this way but on mine it doesnt seem to work.

**Android Monitor log**

```
01-08 03:00:58.288 22447-22447/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                               --------- beginning of crash
01-08 03:01:01.127 1236-1547/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xf4480000) throttle end: throttle time(56)
01-08 03:01:01.151 1550-21914/? D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7f0b1b83d400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f0b1b8bb540
01-08 03:01:01.192 1550-1954/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 3
```

**Weather_MainActivity.java**

```
package com.android.example.cwapp;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;


public class weather_mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String TAG = weather_mainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private CurrentWeather mCurrentWeather;

LocationManager locationManager;

@InjectView(R.id.timeLabel) TextView mTimeLabel;
@InjectView(R.id.temperatureLabel)TextView mTemperatureLabel;
@InjectView(R.id.humidityValue)TextView mHumidityValue;
@InjectView(R.id.precipValue)TextView mPrecipValue;
@InjectView(R.id.summaryLabel)TextView mSummaryLabel;
@InjectView(R.id.iconImageView)ImageView mIconImageView;
@InjectView(R.id.refreshImageView)ImageView mRefreshImageView;
@InjectView(R.id.progressBar)ProgressBar mProgressBar;
@InjectView(R.id.locationLabel)TextView mLocation;

public double latitude /*= 34.7720*/;
public double longitude /*= 32.4297*/;

//Location Manager
private boolean checkLocation() {
    if (!isLocationEnabled())
        showAlert();
    return isLocationEnabled();
}

private void showAlert() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
            .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                    "use this app")
            .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}
private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}

private final LocationListener locationListenerBest = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



    mRefreshImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getForecast(latitude, longitude);
        }
    });

    getForecast(latitude, longitude);

    Log.d(TAG, "Main UI code is running!");
}

private void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude) {
    String apiKey = "6180f6e1b6747c1da3cb4638ea9d2961";
    String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey +
            "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        toggleRefresh();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(forecastUrl)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleRefresh();
                    }
                });
                alertUserAboutError();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleRefresh();
                    }
                });

                try {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG, jsonData);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        mCurrentWeather = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateDisplay();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        alertUserAboutError();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.network_unavailable_message),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void toggleRefresh() {
    if (mProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mRefreshImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private void updateDisplay() {
    float temp = mCurrentWeather.getTemperature();
    String temp2 = Float.toString((temp - 32) * (5 / 9));
    mTemperatureLabel.setText(temp2 + "");
    mTimeLabel.setText("At " + mCurrentWeather.getFormattedTime() + " it will be");
    mHumidityValue.setText(mCurrentWeather.getHumidity() + "");
    mPrecipValue.setText(mCurrentWeather.getPrecipChance() + "%");
    mSummaryLabel.setText(mCurrentWeather.getSummary());
    mLocation.setText(mCurrentWeather.getTimeZone());


    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(mCurrentWeather.getIconId());
    mIconImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}

private CurrentWeather getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    String timezone = forecast.getString("timezone");
    Log.i(TAG, "From JSON: " + timezone);

    JSONObject currently = forecast.getJSONObject("currently");

    CurrentWeather currentWeather = new CurrentWeather();
    currentWeather.setHumidity(currently.getDouble("humidity"));
    currentWeather.setTime(currently.getLong("time"));
    currentWeather.setIcon(currently.getString("icon"));
    currentWeather.setPrecipChance(currently.getDouble("precipProbability"));
    currentWeather.setSummary(currently.getString("summary"));
    currentWeather.setTemperature(currently.getDouble("temperature"));
    currentWeather.setTimeZone(timezone);

    Log.d(TAG, currentWeather.getFormattedTime());

    return currentWeather;
}


private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isAvailable = false;
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        isAvailable = true;
    }

    return isAvailable;
}

private void alertUserAboutError() {
    AlertDialogFragment_weather dialog = new AlertDialogFragment_weather();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
}
```

};

RUN Log

```
  01-09 21:29:30.827 5610-5610/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-09 21:29:30.827 5610-5610/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-09 21:29:30.864 5610-5627/? E/art: Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_2
01-09 21:29:30.869 5614-5614/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-09 21:29:30.870 5614-5614/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-09 21:29:30.916 1548-1596/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '6ba3a14 com.android.example.cwapp/com.android.example.cwapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-09 21:29:31.830 5633-5633/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-09 21:29:31.830 5633-5633/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-09 21:29:32.033 1195-1309/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-09 21:29:33.170 1921-2145/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xedc344f0
01-09 21:30:01.551 5641-5654/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f44b819a240
01-09 21:30:02.902 5641-5654/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f44b1cf8310
01-09 21:30:04.739 5641-5654/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f44b819b580
01-09 21:30:06.655 5641-5654/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f44b1cf8380
01-09 21:30:08.253 5641-5654/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f44b1bed700
01-09 21:30:09.115 5641-5641/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.android.example.cwapp, PID: 5641
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.example.cwapp/com.android.example.cwapp.Places_mainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.android.example.cwapp.Places_mainActivity.onCreate(Places_mainActivity.java:36)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
01-09 21:30:11.307 1548-1601/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f44b1c8f020
01-09 21:30:11.326 1548-1937/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 104)
```

Comment: The problem is in places_mainactivity class. Please post the code.

Comment: 01-09 21:30:09.115 5641-5641/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.android.example.cwapp, PID: 5641
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.example.cwapp/com.android.example.cwapp.Places_mainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Add `CurrentWeather.class` activity in your mainfest like this

```
<activity android:name=".CurrencyConverter_MainActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".weather_mainActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".CurrentWeather"/>
```

Comment: man sorry posted the wrong code. the "weather_mainActivity.class" suppose to be there and not the .CurrentWeather.class

Comment: Please provide the .xml file for weather_mainActivity.class. Maybe there is a problem in it.

Comment: can u have a look now?

Answer (score 0):

You should display your stack trace, but you don't need View.OnClickListner, not sure if that's causing it, but just have weatherbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {...

Other than that, there isn't anything wrong with how you're calling your activity.

Comment: Oh weird... okay, well, it shouldn't, so can you share the stacktrace? Since this is a secondary problem, you can undo what I said and share your original stacktrace for your first problem.

Comment: posted it now!!

Comment: That's not the stacktrace, go to your run tab (bottom left most) and see what's printed when you click that button

Is there a way to chat using stackoverflow?

Comment: posted it now, hope it is the correct one... what do u mean?

Comment: Because it'd be easier than sending message back and forth here

Go to the run window and ctrl + f 'exception' share that whole line and a couple of lines after it, especially if you see a couple that have a different color words.

Comment: there are no exceptions... what i have posted above is the whole log

Comment: Hmm, maybe I don't have enough knowledge to answer this question, but there has to be an exception. If you're using Android Studio, at the bottom, you've clicked on Run tab and you're in the App tab. When you click your ImageButton, an exception of some sort will be thrown. Can you try clicking one more time and ctrl+fing to see if an exception is thrown?

Comment: there are no errors or exceptions... the app runs fine, it just crushes when the apk is finished installing

Comment: You're printing your exceptions incorrectly. You should do e.printstacktrace, not just e, but you should still be able to see your tag...